# RoR3: How do I use the generator to generate views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this namespace:

```
  namespace :manage do
    # Directs /manage/products/* to Manage::ProductsController
    resources :instructors
  end
```

and I want to generate views in the appropriate sub folder and the controller.

What are the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the controller like this:

```
$ rails generate controller manage/instructors
      create  app/controllers/manage/instructors_controller.rb
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/manage/instructors
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/functional/manage/instructors_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/manage/instructors_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/unit/helpers/manage/instructors_helper_test.rb
```

As you can see, Rails has created the views folder for you as well. The views itself you need to create in that folder.

(I used Rails 3.0 in this example, but it holds for older and newer versions as well.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @rdvdijk, but he left out an important note: controller actions can be appended to the end of this command. For example:

`rails generate controller manage/instructors home an_action another_action .. etc`

And it will generate views for each controller action specified.